# Display a one-time button only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I couldn't get this right. I'm doing my business website for our project this coming finals. What I wanted to do is that when the user clicks the homepage for the first time (home.html), it will load a centered button on the middle of the page and the main content is opaque. I tried an IF statement for JS but I couldn't get the logic. Everytime I click the homepage, it continues to load the button. I just wanted it to load once whenever the home.html file is opened.

```
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 3%;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    ul#features li::before {
        content: "\2713    "; /* inserts a check mark */
        color: green;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    ul#features {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    #textOpener {
        display:none;
        position: absolute;
        /* all four properties tries to center the button in the middle */
        top: 40%;
        bottom: 40%;
        left: 40%;
        right: 40%;
    }
    div#mainContent {
        opacity: 0.2;
        visibility: visible;
        background-color: gray;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<script>
if(!localStorage["firstLoad"]) {
    document.getElementById("textOpener").style.display = "block";
    localStorage["firstLoad"] = true;
}
</script>

<p id="textOpener"><a href="#.html" class="button" onclick="showWebpage(i)">Proceed to site</a></p> <!-- this would show up first before the rest of the content -->
<div id="mainContent">
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60dLsffL)

Comment: If `i` starts as 2, and you only ever increment it, it can never be 1.

Comment: (I'm not saying fixing that would solve the problem; it won't, but it's a start.)

Comment: Even if that's so, the JS function still executes. Does the variable reset its value everytime you exit the webpage?

Comment: a var on a page wont help because it is loaded when the page is loaded, that var is not remembered across page loads - look into cookies - of course, some people eat, I mean disable cookies, so you can't get this 100% the way you want

Comment: Web pages are stateless. Every time you reload the page everything is reset.

Comment: It won't solve the problem, but try to use '===' instead of '==' in JS it is safer. Same idea for '!===' and '!=' .
But using cookie or user local storage would be the solution.

Comment: You need to set a [cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or use [localstorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) for this. Variables will reset every time you reload the page.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could do it with [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html):

```
if(!localStorage["firstLoad"]) {
    document.getElementById("textOpener").style.display = "block";
    localStorage["firstLoad"] = true;
}
```

In the CSS set `display:none;` on the `textOpener` div:

```
#textOpener {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    /* all four properties tries to center the button in the middle */
    top: 40%;
    bottom: 40%;
    left: 40%;
    right: 40%;
}
```

This code checks to see if there's a key called `firstLoad` in localStorage, if there's not, then the button is displayed and the key is created(so that the next time the person visits the site, providing they haven't cleared their cache, the code that displays the button will not fire).

## [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60dLsffL/2/)

Comment: Didn't work. I placed the localStorage code under JS. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it should be in the JS section.

Comment: So I need to replace my old <script> code with the new one or do I just insert it after?

Comment: Yes, just place the code within the <script> tags, you can remove the code you had there previously because it won't do what you want it to do.

Comment: I didn't see the button on first load.

Comment: In my Fiddle above it is working just fine.

Comment: I tried it on the fiddle it worked too but not on my .html file though

Comment: Edit your question and post your updated code.

Comment: The updated code is up.

Comment: The problem appears to be that you are executing the script at the top of the page. Move it down to just before the closing `body` tag.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the script is executed before the dom is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //do your code here.
})
```

Otherwise, `document.getElementById("textOpener")` returns nothing.